# Sharing Rules - Markers On User Record To Control Visibility

Tags: administration, security, sharing, sharing-rule, criteria-based-sharing

*Apparently I've made a long time assumption about Sharing Rules that may not be true.*

---

**Sharing Rules Based On User-Record Markers**

If I have a Checkbox on the **User record** called "Allowed To See XYZ", and I have **Accounts** with a Checkbox marker called "XYZ", can I not create a Sharing Rule to allow USERS with that marker to see those ACCOUNTS?  All I am (now) seeing is that we can use is *Groups, Roles* and *Roles+Subordinates*).

We have a **need to allow users to see certain Accounts** that have **one or more of five different markers**.  If the USER record for the person logged on has any of the markers, they are to be able to see those Accounts that have the same markers.

- Some users will have ONE marker and need to see records with that ONE marker
- Some users will have THREE markers and need to see records with ANY ONE of those three markers

---

Account has markers (assume checkboxes):
 - Marker1
 - Marker2
 - Marker3
 - Marker4
 - Marker5

Users will have the **exact same markers.**

I had believed I'd be writing a formula for the criteria along the lines of (assuming checkboxes):

- ( User.Marker1 & Account.Marker1 )
- **or if you prefer**:  if( User.Marker1 & Account.Marker1 ), TRUE, FALSE )

---

*I'm starting to come up with an idea to work around this, but I really don't like it (using the User markers to automatically put them into Groups, then use the Groups to share).  If that's the solution, so be it...*  I just don't want that complexity and maintenance of more routines.

**Help.**

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54147/discussion-on-question-by-amm-sharing-rules-markers-on-user-record-to-control).

Answer (score 1):

I think that this can be solved by doing the following:

> 1. Create a Public Group.
> 2. Create a CheckBox on the Account with name:"XYZ"
> 3. Create the same CheckBox on the User page layout.
> 4. Create a Sharing Rule on Account based on criteria. Criteria is 'checkBox(XYZ) equals true'. Now assign the account to the public
>      group created in point one.
> 5. Write a trigger on the User object to make sure you add users with CheckBox(XYZ=True) to the correct group.

A second, or even a first one, option could be to use a Process Builder to do the same operation, but you need to have points 1 - 4 in place anyway.

Hope it helps.